# Are there any words in the English Language that have three of the same letters together?

Tags: american-english

I was wondering whether there are any words in English that have three words spelt together like *"eee"* or *"ooo"*. I'm not talking about abstract and meaningless words like *"hmmm"* or *"zzz"*, but is there any other such word?

Comment: P.S. Are there words which have more than three letters together?

Comment: Sure, seeër for one. Would you say why you ask? That might help in getting good answers.

Comment: If there were any justice in this world, zoology would have a third consecutive o preceding the l.

Comment: When I ate grilled unagi at a sushi restaurant for the first time, it changed my life—which I now (for convenience) divide into _preeel_ and _posteel_ phases.

Comment: @SvenYargs You should have tried it in Denmark before the spelling reform of 1948, specifically if the eel in question were from the Swedish river _Råå_. Then you could, in the Danish orthography of the time, have had _Raaaaaal_. Don't think there were many sushi restaurants in Scandoland before 1948, though.

Comment: @JEL Usually spelled "seer".

Comment: @WS2, sometimes spelled 'see-er', "used to avoid the customary implications of 'seer'", rare.

Answer (score 6):

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/words-with-same-letter-three-times-in-a-row):

> The answer is not really, because the usual rules of English spelling
>   outlaw triple letters. We put hyphens in words that contain three of
>   the same letters in a row, so as to break the letters up, e.g.
>   *bee-eater*, *bell-like*, *cross-section*, *cross-subsidize*, *joss-stick*, and *shell-less*. A person who flees is a *fleer*, not a *fleeer*, and someone who sees is a *seer*, not a *seeer*. Chaffinches used to be called *chaff finches*, but when the two words were merged,
>   one of the letter 'f's was dropped. That said, written representations
>   of noises often contain triple letters,  such as *brrr*, *shhh*, and
>   *zzz*.

Comment: Well, I guess Trump can't promote a grrrl to bossship, then. XXXX! Maybe those are governed by *unusual* rules, though, or perhaps they're outlaw words.

Comment: It's English: of course they're governed by unusual rules!

Comment: Do I detect mutterings of discontent?

Comment: Your source contradicts itself. Oxford Dictionaries gives both 'grrrl' and 'XXXX' as nouns. It's hard to be a noun when you're not a word. And your source contradicts big brother (*OED*), too, which gives 'bossship' and 'seeër' (alternative sp.) as nouns. The question becomes: what does OD mean by "not really"? has OD forgotten that (as @BladorthinTheGrey points out) English spelling is, well, unusual? Not to mention those outlaws.

Comment: The OP can decide for himself whether he is interested in words in (reasonably) common usage or the odd-balls that you have suggested.

Comment: Oh. Just trying to help. My understanding from the help on good answers is that something more than a general reference quote is expected. That carries on from what is expected in a good question, such as an indication that commonly available references have been consulted and the research mentioned in the question. If you worked your reason for thinking "odd-balls" are excluded by the question into the answer, at least we might have a good answer. I did my bit to suggest a better question in the comments on the question.

Comment: Avoid giving quote-only answers. By all means give credit, as you have done, for other peoples' ideas, but come to your own conclusions and state them clearly as an answer to the question.

Comment: Cryptooology - the study of hidden eggs